# How to double click on .desktop apps to launch them

Tags: .desktop, desktop-apps

I've come across a number of apps that need to be launched by executing a .desktop file. I understand that Canonical have disabled running these kinds of apps for security reasons. How does one accept the risk and allow these apps to run?

Using the terminal and typing [./MyApp.desktop] works and successfully launches the app but that's not an ideal solution for apps that are run often and it leaves an unnecessary terminal window open. How does one launch a .desktop app by simply double clicking on it in Ubuntu?

Suggestions I've come across that do not work:

1. Checking the "Allow executing file as a program" box in properties.
2. Setting the "Open with..." app to "Run Software".

Comment: Place a valid .desktop file into `~/.local/share/applications`, and then use the standard "Windows" key launcher to start the app as normal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me running Ubuntu 22.04.3:

1. Put `someApp.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` folder

   ```
   sudo cp /path/to/someApp.desktop /usr/share/applications
   ```
2. Change file permission

   ```
   sudo chmod +wr /usr/share/application/someApp.desktop
   ```
3. Then you can search the app in "Show applications" panel, as if it was  installed from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that starting your app by launching the `.desktop` file is possible, nor does it work on my side.

Here's what I learned when having the same issue:

- Your file needs to be placed in the directory `/usr/share/applications` if it needs to be available for all users
- Your file needs to be placed in the directory `${HOME}/Desktop` if it should be available only to the current user
- The contents of the file must be exactly correct (I used to have `[Desktop entry]` as the section header but it needed to be `[Desktop Entry]` with a capital E)
- You also need to check "Allow executing file as a program" (as you wrote...)
- I am not sure if you really have to specify a value for "Open with..." (Maybe it is not needed, though I specified "Run Software" as well.)
- After saving the `.desktop` file, an icon should appear on the desktop.
- Right-click that icon. In the context menu which is shown, click "Allow Launching".
- The icon should change to the application's icon (if one is specified in the `.desktop` file) and the application should launch after double-clicking the shortcut icon.

Here's an example `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Comment=MyApp is my favourite app for everything
Exec=/usr/local/myApp/myApp.sh
Icon=/usr/local/myApp/myApp-icon.png
Type=Application
```

There's also a way to check the `.desktop` file for validity:

```
$ desktop-file-validate myApp.desktop
```

If there's no output and the return value of the check is 0 (check with `echo $?`, the shortcut should be fine.
If there's an output, it should indicate what's wrong with the file. The return value should be different from 0 (e.g. 1, also use `echo $?` to check)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but "Allow Launching" doesn't show up (in Ubuntu) and the icon isn't showing. Double clicking does nothing as expected. Seems like Ubuntu has just outright blocked support for the .desktop standard. At least terminal still works.

Comment: did you check the file using `desktop-file-validate`?

Comment: I did validate it

Comment: Ok, did you also select "Allow launching" from the context menu of the desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04

The ideas presented as answers also apply to Ubuntu 22.04. Here
is a test:

copy a desktop file from **~/.local/share/applications** to
**~/Desktop**, then

double-click the .desktop file and
Ubuntu 22.04 replies

**Invalid Permissions on Desktop File**

Also displayed is

**Enable option, Allow Executing File as a Program**

the option located under

**Permissions**  from  **Properties** (right click menu).

Following that advice works. The right-click menu also
has toggle **Allow Launching** which suffices to run the .desktop
file. The **Allow Launching** toggle also sets **Permissions** in **Properties**.

The simplest answer to the question is then: right-click on the .desktop file and select **Allow Launching**. The icon
for the .desktop file changes and double-click launches the .desktop file. To toggle launching, right-click and select **Don't Allow Launching**.

Comment: Right, but this isn't answering the OPs question.